# I can't find the ethernet adapter at all using terminal commands

Tags: internet

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.
The ethernet port is blinking showing that it is working
I run ip addr, and the ethernet port does not show up

Comment: You likely don't have an IP assigned to the ethernet port.  Note that just 'connecting Ethernet' on its own usually isn't sufficient enough to get internet working.  Have you checked the output of `ip link` to see if the ethernet adapter is there and that it says "UP" in the output for that adapter to make sure the link is in fact up?  (This is the first step before we dig into why you don't have an IP or nto)

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

Try to verify that your Ethernet card driver is up and running and shown as a network device, so the output of that command shows groups of devices which you must have at least a (eth0, ethxx, enp0s21u1u2, enp0xx, enp1xx) named device exists in the list:

Using iproute:

```
ip a
```

Using ifconfig:

```
ifconfig
```

So if its okay and shown healthy (but no ip assigned) continue the steps:

Install NetworkManager and (nmtui + nm-applet if you don't have a network-manager gui panel which in most cases you do):

```
sudo apt install network-manager
```

then try to connect Ethernet to your PC/Laptop and let DHCP to assign an ip address to your session, verify to see if you have ip address or not:

```
ip a
```

OR

```
ifconfig
```

otherwise at that point, you must go through installation of the driver of your Ethernet card which you can try to verify the card (product & name) by:
`lspci` command.